# <VirtualHost> cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section

Tags: virtualhost, plesk, vhosts

after I try to use my own vhost.confic instead of using the generated one from Plesk, I just copy the last_httpd.include file and made some modifications - change the document root. But the **/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain redmine.newslab.cz** get some error

```
2013-11-28T10:52:28+01:00 ERR (3): Apache config (13856323480.31924600) generation failed: Syntax error on line 1 of /var/www/vhosts/redmine.newslab.cz/conf/vhost.conf:
<VirtualHost> cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section

Syntax error on line 1 of /var/www/vhosts/redmine.newslab.cz/conf/vhost.conf:
<VirtualHost> cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section
```

**vhost.conf file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerName "redmine.newslab.cz"
        ServerAlias  "www.redmine.newslab.cz"
        ServerAlias  "ipv4.redmine.newslab.cz"
        UseCanonicalName Off


<IfModule mod_suexec.c>
    SuexecUserGroup "redmine.newslab" "psacln"
</IfModule>

    ServerAdmin  "admin@newslab.cz"

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/redmine.newslab.cz/httpdocs/redmine/public"
    CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/redmine.newslab.cz/statistics/logs/access_log plesklog
    ErrorLog  "/var/www/vhosts/redmine.newslab.cz/statistics/logs/error_log"


<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir "/var/www/vhosts/redmine.newslab.cz/web_users"
</IfModule>

    ScriptAlias  "/cgi-bin/" "/var/www/vhosts/redmine.newslab.cz/cgi-bin/"


    Redirect permanent /plesk-stat https://redmine.newslab.cz/plesk-stat
    Redirect permanent /webstat https://redmine.newslab.cz/webstat
    Redirect permanent /webstat-ssl https://redmine.newslab.cz/webstat-ssl
    Redirect permanent /ftpstat https://redmine.newslab.cz/ftpstat
    Redirect permanent /anon_ftpstat https://redmine.newslab.cz/anon_ftpstat
    Redirect permanent /awstats-icon https://redmine.newslab.cz/awstats-icon


    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        SSLEngine off
    </IfModule>

SetEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/redmine.newslab.cz/etc/php.ini

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    FcgidInitialEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/redmine.newslab.cz/etc/php.ini
    FcgidMaxRequestLen 16777216
</IfModule>

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/redmine.newslab.cz/httpdocs/redmine/public>

<IfModule mod_perl.c>
    <Files ~ (\.pl$)>
        SetHandler perl-script
        PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry
        Options ExecCGI
        allow from all
        PerlSendHeader On
    </Files>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_python.c>
    <Files ~ (\.py$)>
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler
    </Files>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    <Files ~ (\.fcgi)>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    </Files>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    <Files ~ (\.php)>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper .php
        Options +ExecCGI
        allow from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>

        Options -Includes +ExecCGI

    </Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/redmine.newslab.cz/statistics">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Domain statistics"
    AuthUserFile "/var/www/vhosts/redmine.newslab.cz/pd/d..httpdocs@plesk-stat"
    require  valid-user
</Directory>
Alias /error_docs /var/www/vhosts/redmine.newslab.cz/error_docs
ErrorDocument 400 /error_docs/bad_request.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error_docs/unauthorized.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error_docs/forbidden.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error_docs/not_found.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error_docs/internal_server_error.html
ErrorDocument 405 /error_docs/method_not_allowed.html
ErrorDocument 406 /error_docs/not_acceptable.html
ErrorDocument 407 /error_docs/proxy_authentication_required.html
ErrorDocument 412 /error_docs/precondition_failed.html
ErrorDocument 414 /error_docs/request_uri_too_long.html
ErrorDocument 415 /error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html
ErrorDocument 501 /error_docs/not_implemented.html
ErrorDocument 502 /error_docs/bad_gateway.html
ErrorDocument 503 /error_docs/maintenance.html

</VirtualHost>
```

Do have anybody idea what is wrong. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple. Your `vhost.conf` is included **inside** the one generated by Plesk, it doesn't replace the Plesk config. That means you need to strip your `vhost.conf` from `VirtualHost` directive and other duplicated content. Keep there only directives which you need and which Plesk doesn't add itself.

Comment: I have the same error and I have no VIrtualHost directive in vhost.conf, only this: `<IfModule mpm_event_module>MaxRequestWorkers 1000</IfModule>`

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. Had this issue when using an Apache Docker Image webdevops/php-apache.